# BASH: Convert hex representation inside a string to binary equivalent

Tags: linux, bash, binary, hex

I  want to check inside a binary file if it matches a binary pattern.

For that, I'm using clamAV signature database

```
Exploit.HTML.ObjectType:3:*:3c6f626a65637420747970653d222f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f
```

I code this to retrieve the hex signature string

```
signature=$(echo "$line" |awk -F':' '{ print $4 }')
```

Moreover I would like to change hex string to binary

```
tmp=$(echo -n $signature | sed 's/\([0-9A-F]\{2\}\)/\\\\\\x\1/gI' | xargs print)
```

Finally I would like to check if my file ( *$raw_file_path* ) matches my binary pattern (now in *$tmp*)

```
test_var=$(cat $raw_file_path | grep -U -P "$tmp")
```

I don't why it doesn't work.

If you have any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: grep and unix tools in general are not designed to read binary files, as they contain \000 (null) characters as part of their normal data. Unix tools rely on reading lines of data, that are separated with end-of-line characters (\n, or \r\n in Windows filesystems). Null characters void this basic model of processing. You may find a combination options to `od` that will allow you to do what you want. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
line=Exploit.HTML.ObjectType:3:*:3c6f626a65637420747970653d222f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f2f
printf $(sed 's/.*://;s/\(..\)/\\x\1/g' <<< "$line")
```

Which yields:

```
<object type="////////////
```

You can put the bin output in a variable thus:

```
printf -v variable $(sed 's/.*://;s/\(..\)/\\x\1/g' <<< "$line")
```

Now, please avoid a useless use of `cat`!

```
grep -U "$variable" "$raw_file_path"
```

is enough. If you want to test the result of `grep` (and ask `grep` to be quiet):

```
if grep -qU "$variable" "$raw_file_path"; then
    echo "Pattern found"
else
    echo "Pattern not found"
fi
```

Comment: Well usage of `printf` and `sed`: +1! (remark: instead of `s/.*:// ... $line` you could use bash variable motor and write: `$(sed 's/\(..\)/\\x\1/g;' <<<${line##*:})`. But thanks, I did'nt read `-v` option of printf until today! (+2 as *this was usefull for me*;-) Well, I'll go to bash to see how to use *Arrays* or even *Associatives Arrays* with this `printf -v`. And welcome around there!

Comment: @F.Hauri You're right about the parameter expansion. Though I have this habit that when I start forking a `sed`, I try to get as much of it as I can (when reasonably possible). Besides, my benchmarks prove that in this case, the 100% `sed` method is almost 1% faster (!) than the `sed`-parameter expansion method `:-)`. About `printf` and arrays, there are no options that I know to tell `printf` to construct an array (as there is, e.g., with the `-a` option of the `read` builtin).

Comment: thanks!
I will use signature=$(echo "$line" | awk -F':' '{ print $4 }')


printf -v variable $(sed 's/\(..\)/\\x\1/g;'' <<< "$signature")


grep -U "$variable" "$raw_file_path"

Comment: Upto now, I use `sed` to build a bash array or even associative array, than fork to/from `eval` : ` declare -A fields;eval "fields=("$(df -PlkT / | sed -ne '/\/$/{s/^[^ \t]*[ \t]\+\([^ \t]\+\)[ \t]\+\([^ \t]\+\)[ \t]\+\([^ \t]\+\)[ \t]\+\([^ \t]\+\)[ \t]\+.*/[fs]="\1" [tot]="\2" [use]="\3" [ava]="\4"/p}')")"`

Comment: @F.Hauri How about: `f=( _ fs tot use ava _ ); { read; read _ ${f[@]} _; } < <(df -PlkT /); declare -A fields; for i in ${f[@]}; do [[ $i != _ ]] && fields[$i]=${!i}; done` ? (don't know if it's portable though). But `eval` is evil! `:-)`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: `eval` is very nice if you know what you do! Your purpose put $use, $ava and so on my environ. I just want: `fields`, so : `declare -A fields; { read;read fields[mpnt] fields[fs] fields[tot] fields[use] fields[ava] foo; } < <(df -PlkT /)` ... ( but don't forget to `unset use ava tot` ;-)

Comment: I doesn't understand.Have you a beginner version please.

Comment: @user1778354 We were just talking about something else... sorry that's a bad thing to do `;-)`